# FTP can connect w/o authentication in browser but not in code

Tags: python, security, authentication, ftp

I am trying to connect to an FTP server in a python script. I can access the FTP server from the browser without issue, but when I try to run the following:

```
ftp = FTP('garner.ucsd.edu')
ftp.cwd('pub/products')
```

it fails with `error_perm: 530 Please login with USER and PASS.`

But I don't have a username and password for this FTP--how come my browser seems to get past this authentication just fine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that Firefox was automatically authenticating with empty strings for the username and password.

These are the default arguments in `ftp.login`, so the following fixes the script:

```
ftp = FTP('garner.ucsd.edu')
ftp.login()
ftp.cwd('pub/products')
```

This is actually in the [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ftplib.html) too, I just didn't realize it was actually necessary.

Comment: @ρss I know--it says I will be able to accept in 2 days.

Comment: It shouldn't be 2 days, it should be 15 minutes

Comment: @Barmar I think the 2-day limit is only for self-answered questions.